# UPDATE con datos de la propia tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, sqlite

Por claridad, he extraído las dos columnas relevantes de una tabla que tengo que modificar. El campo ***nid*** tiene siempre dos números repetidos y los del campo ***did*** son todos diferentes como se puede ver aquí:

| nid | did |
| --- | --- |
| 1515961052422 | 1603499989463 |
| 1515961052422 | 1603500132346 |
| 1527265654785 | 1603500477464 |
| 1527265654785 | 1603500477462 |
| 1595538785520 | 1609436341644 |
| 1595538785520 | 1609436355808 |

Necesito hacer mediante un UPDATE con SQL que para cada dos ***nid*** con igual número, es decir, por ejemplo fila uno y dos, los ***did*** tengan el número de su campo replicado en los dos. Es decir, uno de los ***did*** se sobreescribiría sobre el otro, de forma que quedaría así:

| nid | did |
| --- | --- |
| 1515961052422 | 1603499989463 |
| 1515961052422 | 1603499989463 |
| 1527265654785 | 1603500477464 |
| 1527265654785 | 1603500477464 |
| 1595538785520 | 1609436341644 |
| 1595538785520 | 1609436341644 |

En este caso he escrito el primer ***did*** que me encuentro de arriba a abajo sobre el segundo, pero no importa cual se conserve, lo importante es que las filas en que dos los dos ***nid*** son iguales, suceda lo mismo con los ***did*** y se decanten por el primero o el segundo, pero que sean el mismo.

Necesito encontrar la SQL que mediante un UPDATE haga esto (si es que es posible y, si no lo es, saberlo). Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En MySql podés hacer algo así:

Yo seteo el did mas grande (MAX), pero podés setear el mas chico (MIN).

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla AS t1, (SELECT nid, MAX(did) as max_did
                            FROM nombre_tabla
                            GROUP BY nid) AS t2

SET t1.did = t2.max_did

WHERE t2.nid = t1.nid AND t2.max_did != t1.did
```

SQLite >= 3.33.0

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla AS t1

    SET did = t2.max_did

FROM (SELECT nid, max(did) as max_did
      FROM nombre_tabla 
      GROUP BY nid) AS t2

WHERE t2.nid = t1.nid AND t2.max_did != t1.did
```

SQLite anteriores:

```
UPDATE nombre_tabla AS t

    SET did = (SELECT max(did)
               FROM nombre_tabla AS t2
               WHERE t2.nid = t.nid
               GROUP BY nid);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte. La verdad es que estoy trabajando en SQLite y no sé si por eso me da fallos. Al no manejarme desde hace mucho tiempo con MySql, he intentado utilizar un conversor en línea para que me adopte la sintaxis a las particularidades de SQLite pero me sigue fallando.

Comment: De nada! Seguramente, ¿por que la tagueaste como MySql? Ahí la voy a actualizar para SQLite.

Comment: Creo que podría ser la 3.6.23.

Comment: Probalo ahí, para SQLite versión >= 3.33.0 no lo pude probar, la otra la probé en una versión anterior y funciona.

Comment: Me falla, pero desconozco por qué. Si ejecuto la SQLite >= 3.33.0, me dice:

Ejecución terminada con errores.
Resultado: near "FROM": syntax error
En la línea 1:
UPDATE cards AS t1

Y si ejecuto la SQLite anteriores:, muestra:

Ejecución terminada con errores.
Resultado: near "t": syntax error
En la línea 1:
UPDATE cards t

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122964/discussion-between-nachospiu-and-pip).

Comment: Ahí la corregí, me faltaba el "AS". Usa la segunda query porque tu versión de SQLite es < 3.33.0.

Comment: Perdona, no lo he podido mirar hasta ahora. Efectivamente, ya funciona y hace su efecto de manera totalmente correcta. Gracias por la ayuda, tu código SQL tiene todo el sentido del mundo y, aunque me acerqué, no supe hacerlo bien.

Comment: De nada! Me alegra haberte podido ayudar.